# Is it possible to commit only one file through grgit plugin for gradle.?

Tags: git, gradle, gradle-plugin, grgit

Is it possible to commit only one file through grgit plugin for gradle.?

I have modified the `version.properties` file and I need to commit only that particular file back to git using grgit plugin.

But when i Commit back to git whole project is getting committed back to git branch .

my code

```
task pushToGit
{
    def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: '.')
    grgit.commit(message: 'Committing Version Property Changes', all: true)
    grgit.push(force: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `all` option on `grgit.commit` is similar to the `git commit -a` flag. It will commit changes to all tracked files. To only commit one, you need to add it to the index first, then commit.

```
task pushToGit
{
    def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: '.')
    grgit.add(patterns: ['version.properties'])
    grgit.commit(message: 'Committing Version Property Changes')
    grgit.push(force: true) // not sure I would recommend this
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ajoberstar... Is it possible to create a Tag while committing and pushing the change.

Comment: You'll probably want to post a second question for that.